# Restart read required when migrating existing application from PostgreSQL to YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I am trying to migrate an existing application from PostgreSQL to YugabyteDB using a cluster with 3 nodes.
The smoke tests run fine but I  received the following error as soon as I use more than one concurrent user:

```
com.yugabyte.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Query error: Restart read required at: { read: { physical: 1648067607419747 } local_limit: { physical: 1648067607419747 } global_limit: <min> in_txn_limit: <max> serial_no: 0 }
at com.yugabyte.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
at com.yugabyte.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
at com.yugabyte.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
at com.yugabyte.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
at com.yugabyte.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:408)
at com.yugabyte.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:162)
at com.yugabyte.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:151)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:219)
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:4354)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:230)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:340)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:284)
at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:2843)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.fetch(DefaultDSLContext.java:4749)
```

I am using the version 11.2-YB-2.13.0.1-b0

It is a clinical data repository implemented using Spring Boot and JOOQ. The application exposes a REST API to store and query clinical documents inside the database.
I try to execute a JMeter test plan that creates and queries random documents using 10 concurrent users during a fixed period (5min).

Until now, we were using PostgreSQL which seems to have Read Committed as the default isolation level. So, I assume that I have to change the isolation at the application level as Spring uses the one defined by the database by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that the default isolation level of PostgreSQL and YugabyteDB is not the same.
Read Committed Isolation is supported only if the gflag `yb_enable_read_committed_isolation` is set to true. By default this gflag is false and in this case the Read Committed isolation level of Yugabyte's transactional layer falls back to the stricter Snapshot Isolation (in which case READ COMMITTED and READ UNCOMMITTED of YSQL also in turn use Snapshot Isolation).

Can you change the isolation level as above for YugabyteDB? Please refer to this doc link  for more details - https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/explore/transactions/isolation-levels/

It should work much better after the change.